# Retrieve source code from Package/module

Tags: node-modules

How can I download the source code folder of the npm module?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-d3-charts

Comment: You can use `npm view [package name] dist.tarball` which will return the URL of the compressed package file. I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `npm view [package name] dist.tarball` which will return the URL of the compressed package file.